# Highcharts tilted view

Tags: highcharts

I have problems with displaying an highcharts area chart.
At the jsFiddle link you can see that the red area (with negative values) is tilt or rotated or however I should describe this ;-)

Any idea what i have to do, or is this bug?

Best regards
Andi

```
[http://jsfiddle.net/7jGx5/1/]
```

Comment: and how do you want it to be, negative values are displayed as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data for red series should be sorted by x, ascending.

EDIT:

```
[Date.UTC(2013, 3, 8, 8, 46), -177],
                [Date.UTC(2013, 3, 8, 8, 47), -1072],
                [Date.UTC(2013, 3, 8, 8, 48), -2199],
                [Date.UTC(2013, 3, 8, 8, 49), -2265],
                [Date.UTC(2013, 3, 8, 7, 52), 308],
                [Date.UTC(2013, 3, 8, 7, 53), 277],
                [Date.UTC(2013, 3, 8, 7, 54), 317],
                [Date.UTC(2013, 3, 8, 7, 55), 154],
                [Date.UTC(2013, 3, 8, 7, 56), 296],
                [Date.UTC(2013, 3, 8, 7, 57), 200],
                [Date.UTC(2013, 3, 8, 7, 58), -237],
                [Date.UTC(2013, 3, 8, 7, 59), 207],
                [Date.UTC(2013, 3, 8, 8, 0), 128],
                [Date.UTC(2013, 3, 8, 8, 1), 276],
                [Date.UTC(2013, 3, 8, 8, 2), 225],
```

Comment: as you can see in the fiddle the data is sorted by datetime, i think ;-)

Comment: @Andi_H please take look at updated post, because as I see, data is not sorted, as I posted earlier.